# Computer will not authenticate anything

Tags: password, authentication

I recently downloaded Ubuntu and now I am trying to start to use the new OS. However to do pretty much anything I want to do I need to "authenticate" things. I am the administrator and I have put into place my password to log into the computer. I assumed that this is the password to be used to authenticate things. As I have looked around the web this is what seems to be true. However it will not accept that as the correct password and does not allow me to do what I want after three tries. It keeps saying that "your authentication attempt was unsuccessful. please try again." Is there a different password that I am supposed to use. If not is there a way to change that password or at least figure out what that password is.

[image: Authentication not accepted]

Comment: I knew my password because I used it to log into my account multiple times. It just would not accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I shut down my computer and booted it up in Windows 10. Then I shut it down again and booted it up in Ubuntu and this seems to have fixed the issue. However just turning it off and back on again without booting to Windows first did not fix the issue.

Comment: Likely cause: Have you turned off Fast Boot/Fast Startup in Windows?